# NativeScript ListView scroll event

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular, ios11.4

How can I detect when a `ListView` is scrolled?

I tried wrapping the `ListView` in a `ScrollView` and using the `scroll` event on the `ScrollView`. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the PanGesture on a ListView to capture when a user is scrolling up or down.

```
  const panEvent$ = fromEvent(this.listView, 'pan').pipe(map(
    (event: PanGestureEventData) => event.deltaY
  ));
```

This will take my listView property and only emit the Y values. you can then determine if they are moving up or down if Y is greater than 0